# Problem occurs when use find function in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I try to get data from the backend and view that data in the frontend. To do that I tried this code:

```
function VProfile() {

    const buyerId=(localStorage.getItem("userId"));
    console.log(buyerId);

    const [buyerDetails, setBuyerDetails] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`/getBuyerDetails`)
            .then((response) => setBuyerDetails(response.data.existingBuyers))
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }, []);

    console.log(buyerDetails);

    const oneBuyer = buyerDetails?.find(oneBuyer => oneBuyer.buyerId === buyerId);
    console.log(oneBuyer);
}
```

When I call the API I get a length 3 array of objects. This is an image of the data.

[image: Results of API call]

Then I try to find the data of a specific buyer using the `find` function. To do that I use this `const oneBuyer = buyerDetails?.find(oneBuyer => oneBuyer.buyerId === buyerId)` code. But then I got an error that says `TypeError: buyerDetails.find is not a function`. How do I silve this problem?

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You initialize the state with an object (`{}`):

```
const [buyerDetails, setBuyerDetails] = useState({});
```

Objects don't have `.find`, only arrays do.

You might want to initialize it to an empty array (`[]`), or `undefined` to more clearly signal the case that the data is not yet loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You call `setBuyerDetails` asynchronously, **so at the moment when you log them, the data hasn't arrived**, due to `console.log` you are being "deceived" to believe the data is there. From docs:

> Please be warned that if you log objects in the latest versions of
> Chrome and Firefox what you get logged on the console is a reference
> to the object, **which is not necessarily the 'value' of the object at
> the moment in time you call console.log()**, but it is the value of the
> object at the moment you open the console.

To avoid that error you can initialize that variable with empty array initially:

```
const [buyerDetails, setBuyerDetails] = useState([]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it something like that and initialize with an `array` and you are using async operations so please add the `loading` flag

```
function VProfile() {
    const buyerId=(localStorage.getItem("userId"));
    console.log(buyerId);

    const [buyerDetails, setBuyerDetails] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`/getBuyerDetails`)
            .then((response) => {
                setBuyerDetails(response.data.existingBuyers));
                setLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error(err));
    }, []);

    console.log(buyerDetails);

    if (loading) return <p>loading....</p>

    const oneBuyer = buyerDetails?.find(oneBuyer => oneBuyer.buyerId === buyerId);
    console.log(oneBuyer);
}
```

Comment: There's no need to use a separate state atom for the "loading" state when you can use e.g. `undefined` (or any other "out-of-band" value) for the data to be loaded to signal the same. :)

Comment: Yes, you are right but this solution will works perfect when there are multiple calls

Comment: It's still likely not worth it to keep it a state atom - you could just as well do `const loading = (data1 === undefined || data2 === undefined);`...

Comment: Yes that is also an option and its valid because setState will create new rerender